# Explain Keyed Tuple output from SQLAlchemy ORM Query using Aliased

Tags: orm, sqlalchemy

Please help me improve/understand queries using an aliased class. Consider an example with movement between two locations described as follows.

```
class Location(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'location'
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)

class Movement(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'movement'
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
  from_id = Column(None, ForeignKey('location.id')
  to_id = Column(None, ForeignKey('location.id')

  from_location = relationship('Location', foreign_keys = from_id)
  to_location = relationship('Location', foreign_keys = to_id)
```

To join three tables in a query, I'm using the aliased() function from sqlalchemy.orm:

```
FromLocation = aliased(Location)
ToLocation = aliased(Location)

r = session.query(Movement, FromLocation, ToLocation).\
    join(FromLocation, Movement.from_id == FromLocation.id).\
    join(ToLocation, Movement.to_id == ToLocation.id).first()
```

First question is "What's the intelligent way to work with `r`?" The query returns a keyed tuple, but the only key is 'Movement', there's no 'FromLocation' as I would expect. I can get it with r[1], but that's easily broken.

Second question is "Did I put in the relationship right?" I didn't think I would have to specify the join target so explicitly. But without the targets specified, I get an error:

```
r = session.query(Movement, FromLocation, ToLocation).\
    join(FromLocation).\
    join(ToLocation)

InvalidRequestError: Could not find a FROM clause to join from.  Tried joining to <AliasedClass at 0x10cfa16d8; Location>, but got: Can't determine join between 'movement' and '%(4512717680 location)s'; tables have more than one foreign key constraint relationship between them. Please specify the 'onclause' of this join explicitly.
```

Yes, I see the two foreign keys, but how to map them correctly?

Comment: First of all: what are you trying to query? If `Movement` instances, then just leave `sesion.query(Movement)` to query movements. Once you receive the result(s), get `Locations` just navigating relationships: using `my_movement.from_location` and `my_movement.to_location`

Comment: @van Movement and Location have additional attributes: Movement.time and Location.latitude, for example. Ordered by time, the query would produce coordinates to plot a path. Seems better than looping through multiple queries on Location where id == my_movement.from_location, but I guess that's another way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option-1:** To have names in the `KeyedTuple`, just add names to the aliases:

```
FromLocation = aliased(Location, name="From")
ToLocation = aliased(Location, name="To")

# ...
print(r.keys)
# >>>> ['Movement', 'From', 'To']
```

**Option-2:** Create a query to return only `Movement` instance(s), but preload both locations. Please note also alternative `join` syntax by specifying `relationship` instead of key pairs.

```
r = (session.query(Movement)
        .join(FromLocation, Movement.from_location)
        .join(ToLocation, Movement.to_location)
        .options(contains_eager(Movement.from_location, alias=FromLocation))
        .options(contains_eager(Movement.to_location, alias=ToLocation))
    ).first()
print(r)
print(r.from_location)
print(r.to_location)
```